# Multiple partial file renames from CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I have a folder of source images (`.jpg`) that I would like to rename based of data in a `.csv`.

The rename will be on two parts of the filename, the file names look like `part1.part2.jpg`

Here is what the `.csv` looks like:

[image]

I have a partially working script, but it throws errors stating it cannot find the original files and always fails to correctly rename the last file addressed in the `.csv`.

```
#read the csv doc provided to get the old Part1s
$csvData = Import-Csv '.\*.csv'

#get the source images
$sourceImages = GCI '.\Source_Images' -Recurse

#rename source file
$csvData | % {
$oldPart1 = $_.OldPart1
$newPart1 = $_.NewPart1
$oldPart2 = $_.OldPart2
$newPart2 = $_.NewPart2
    foreach($sourceImage in $sourceImages){
        $sourceImage | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $oldPart1, $newPart1 -replace $oldPart2, $newPart2}   
    }
}
```

I can tell I am close, but I am obviously missing something. I think the `foreach` within the `%` is causing some issue.

Comment: Just move `$sourceImages = GCI '.\Source_Images' -Recurse` to just before your `foreach($sourceImage in $sourceImages)`. Are these oldparts and newparts exact or theoretical because there are simpler ways to replace `something` with `something2`.

Comment: Haha good question, yes they are theoretical :)

Comment: @AdminOfThings this works, thank you. If you resubmit this as an answer I will mark it correct. Any help understanding my error is also greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are sticking with your current logic, you just need to reread the directory when your variables are updated. This is needed because once the files are renamed in each loop iteration, they are different objects and can no longer be found in the original `$sourceImages`.

```
$csvData = Import-Csv '.\*.csv'

#rename source file
$csvData | % {
    $oldPart1 = $_.OldPart1
    $newPart1 = $_.NewPart1
    $oldPart2 = $_.OldPart2
    $newPart2 = $_.NewPart2
    #get the source images
    $sourceImages = GCI '.\Source_Images' -Recurse
    foreach($sourceImage in $sourceImages){
        $sourceImage | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $oldPart1, $newPart1 -replace $oldPart2, $newPart2}   
    }
}
```