# Partial file rename in powershell with CSV source

Tags: powershell

I want to rename parts of the filename of a collection of `.jpg` files. I have built a `.csv` table with a column of the old partial name and the new partial names. File naming is `part1.part2.part3.jpg`, and I would like to replace part 1 only. The `.csv` looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code, which seems to only search for the first original name and first new name in the `.csv` for each source image, effectively only renaming one of the images.

```
#import naming conventions
$csvData = Import-Csv ".\Orig_to_new.csv"

#rename source file
$csvData | % {
    $original = $_.Original
    $new = $_.Real

    #get the source images
    $sourceImages = GCI -Recurse -Filter *.jpg ".\Renamed_Archive"
    
    foreach($sourceImage in $sourceImages){

        $sourceImage | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $original, $new}
    }
}
```

Ideally the script would see each sourceImage's original name, and replace it with the new name based on the `.csv` doc, example change 'abc' to 'xyz' and '123' to '456' based on the provided `.csv` table.

Disclaimer: I have asked a similar question before and thought I had a working model but I cant get it to function.

Thanks

Comment: I thought this thread provided a working model but I am still encountering issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817674/multiple-partial-file-renames-from-csv-with-powershell

Comment: Can you post a full sample filename, along with 1) what your current script changes it to as well as 2) what you expect it to be?

Comment: sample file name would be abc.0001.xx_xxx.jpg

expected out come is change 'abc' to 'xyz' based on the provided .csv table.

Comment: And that's already working ("seems to only search for the first original name and first new name in the .csv for each source image, effectively only renaming one of the images."), but it doesn't work for files named `123.0001.xx_xxx.jpg`? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If i add a `write-host` to call out the `$current` and `$new` during the `foreach $sourceImage` bit it reads the first line only, they never change.

Comment: Do this different parts of the file name always have a separator (a dot for example).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon file naming structure is in the question and in my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with this, the renaming part of the script I assume you already know what to do.

- First, convert your CSV to a hashtable
- Then you can loop over all your images, split their name using `.` as a separator (I use `(?=\.)` to preserve the dots)
- We know that the position 0 of the array is what you want to replace, here you can use your hashtable to get the new name of that part and replace the position 0 of the Name array for the new Name we get from your CSV.
- Ultimately you join the array again into a string.

```
$csv=@'
Original,New
abc,xyz
123,456
qwe,rty
'@|convertfrom-csv

$nameMap=@{}

$csv.foreach({
    if(-not $nameMap.ContainsKey($_.Original))
    {
        $nameMap.Add($_.Original,$_.New)
    }
})

$sourceImages=gci -Recurse -Filter *.jpg -Path .

foreach($image in $sourceImages)
{
    $name=$image.Name -split '(?=\.)'
    $newPart1=$nameMap[$name[0]]
    $name[0]=$newPart1
    $newName=-join $name

    'Old Name: {0} // New Name: {1}' -f $image.Name,$newName
}

# Looks like this:

PS /~> ./script.ps1
Old Name: 123.part2.part3.jpg // New Name: 456.part2.part3.jpg
Old Name: abc.part2.part3.jpg // New Name: xyz.part2.part3.jpg
Old Name: qwe.part2.part3.jpg // New Name: rty.part2.part3.jpg
```

Edit: Adding full script code here, as well as new If condition.

```
#import naming conventions
$csv = Import-Csv ".\table.csv"

$nameMap=@{}

$csv.foreach({
    if(-not $nameMap.ContainsKey($_.Original)){
        $nameMap.Add($_.Original,$_.New)
    }
})

#identify files for renaming
$sourceImages = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.jpg -Path ".\images"

foreach($image in $sourceImages)
{
    $name=$image.Name -split '(?=\.)'

    # Adding this If condition, reasoning below.
    # Rename files only If the position 0 of the splitted name is in our nameMap hashtable.
    # This is because if it's not there you would end up with files named like:
    # "..part2.part3.jpg" because $newPart1 var would be null.
    if($nameMap.ContainsKey($name[0]))
    {
        $newPart1=$nameMap[$name[0]]
        $name[0]=$newPart1
        $newName=-join $name

        'Old Name: {0} // New Name: {1}' -f $image.Name,$newName

        Rename-Item $image.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to copy and paste the csv contents into the code like you have here on lines 2-5 ?

Comment: No that’s to simulate importing the CSV

Comment: @Garrett no, that was just for me to have something to test on.

Comment: I removed lines 1-6 as they dont seem to be part of the code.

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to fit the above logic into the re-name script and it seems to work, but it's not really the full answer. I'll post the final script as a separate answer, please feel free to copy/paste it and i will mark your edited reply as the answer.